# Telerik winform controls disappear from toolbox every time VS is closed

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, telerik

I'm using Telerik winform controls with VS2015. I add controls manually in toolbox. I can work as far as VS is running. When I close VS then they disappear. Next time to work with them I need to add again. I've faced same problem before with infragistics controls. Is there any solution that keeps controls sticking in toolbox all the time?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

We are heavy into the Telerik control suite for WinForms and don't experience the behavior that you are.  You must have an active Telerik subscription for this to work as well.  Here are the steps I would recommend:

1. Download and Install the Telerik Control Panel: http://www.telerik.com/blogs/introducing-the-telerik-control-panel
2. Download UI for Winforms product with Telerik Control Panel.
3. Restart Visual Studio.
4. You will now have a Telerik meun item.  In there click "Configure Project" which install the latest Telerik controls and make them available to your current project via the toolbar.

If this doesn't work I would suggest re-installing Visual Studio and then repeating the above steps.